# How do I use the value passed by reference to update to remove the occurrence within a doublylinkedlist

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I am using a doubly linked list and am trying to remove a node based on the user's input. The value is passed by reference to a function named remove. However, the code I have written doesn't seem to work with a value passed by reference... or perhaps I am not initializing it correctly. I get the "error error: ‘_ret’ was not declared in this scope"

```
void DoublyLinkedList::remove(const string& s)
{
 if (current == nullptr){
   //return nullptr;
}
 Node *next_ = current->next;
 Node *prev_ = current->prev;
 //I THINK THIS IS WHERE I AM WRONG???
 _ret = Node(s);
 _ret = nullptr;
 //s _ret = nullptr;


 if (next_ != nullptr && prev_!=nullptr){
 current->prev->next = current->next;
 current->next->prev = current->prev;
 delete current->data;
 delete current;
 current = next_;
 _ret = current->data;
 }
 else if (next_ == nullptr && prev_==nullptr){
   this->head = this->tail = nullptr;
   delete current->data;
   delete current;
   current = nullptr;
   _ret = nullptr;
 }
 else if (next_ != nullptr && prev_ == nullptr){
   head = head->next;
   head->prev = nullptr;
   delete current->data;
   delete current;
   current = next_;
   _ret = current->data;
}
else if (next_ == nullptr && prev_ != nullptr){
   tail = tail->prev;
   tail->next = nullptr;
   delete current->data;
   delete current;
   current = nullptr;
   _ret = nullptr;
 }
}
```

Comment: `_ret = Node(s);` is wrong on couple of accounts. 1. You have not specified its type. 2. You don't need to construct a `Node` object to search for the node that has the given value.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is right, you have not declared `_ret` in the function. That means, you have not provided the variable's type.

Besides, is this some kind of exercise to implement the list? If not, why don't you simply use `std::list`?

Comment: I am trying to use that parameter passed into this function to delete a node in my doubly linked list. I am sure there is probably issues in my logic but I first cannot figure out how to even access the information.

Comment: @Jay, you did not show how `Node` structure or class looks like. However, assuming `Node::data` is a `std::string` or a pointer to it, you should iterate over the nodes from head to tail and check which node contains the passed string as its data. This is the node to remove.